# Como cargo el contenido de un Spinner en un TextView?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin.android, textview, android-spinner

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando cargue el contenido que exista dentro del Spinner se me cargue en un textview, este es el codigo donde se ejecuta todos los datos del spinner, como dato extra esta conectado a una base de datos MySQL.

```
class DataParser : AsyncTask
{
    Context c;
    private Spinner sp;
    private String jsonData;
    JavaList<string> spacecrafts=new JavaList<string>(); 
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public DataParser(Context c, Spinner sp, string jsonData)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.sp = sp;
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        base.OnPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.SetTitle("Cargando información");
        pd.SetMessage("Por favor espere");
        pd.Show();

    }

    protected override Object DoInBackground(params Object[] @params)
    {
        return this.ParseData();
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);

        pd.Dismiss();

        if (Integer.ParseInt(result.ToString()) == 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(c,"No se puede analizar",ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<string>(c,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,spacecrafts);
            sp.Adapter = adapter;

            sp.ItemSelected += sp_ItemSelected;
        }
    }

    void sp_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(c, spacecrafts[e.Position], ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }

    private int ParseData()
    {
        try
        {
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            spacecrafts.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.Length(); i++)
            {
                jo = ja.GetJSONObject(i);

                String name = jo.GetString("nomb_ingrediente");

                spacecrafts.Add(name);

            }

            return 1;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Y acá esta el MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private Spinner sp;
    private String urlAddress = "localhost:7777/carpeta/buscar.php";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        sp = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.sp);
        TextView text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Button downloadBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.downloadBtn);
        downloadBtn.Click += downloadBtn_Click;


    }

    void downloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Downloader(this, urlAddress, sp).Execute();
    }
}
```

Solo quiero cargar el spinner en el textview que aparece acá, muchas gracias

Comment: Prueba mi respuesta, AsyncTask en C# no es tan util como los Tasks, ya que los Tasks son mas potentes y te permiten hacer muchas cosas. Me imagino que la clase Downloader es un AsyncTask asi que puedes convertirla a una tarea asincrona de C# asi practicas y aprendes a utilizar esta forma, ya que en pocas palabras AsyncTask no es tan util en Xamarin Android. Buena suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar utilizar la [programación asíncrona de C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443(v=vs.120)) que es una ventaja y mas potente que el `AsyncTask` para ejecutar tareas sin que se bloquee el hilo principal.

En los metodos asincronos de C# existen dos palabras claves o `keywords`.

> `async` : Use el modificador `async` para especificar que un método,
>   una expresión lambda o un método anónimo es asincrónico. Si se utiliza
>   este modificador en un método o una expresión, se hace referencia al
>   mismo como método asincrónico.
>
> `await`: El operador `await` se aplica a una tarea en un método
>   asincrónico para suspender la ejecución del método hasta que se
>   complete la tarea esperada. La tarea representa el trabajo en curso.

Esto quiere decir, que todo lo que este despues del await, sera procesado, luego de que se obtenga el resultado. Por lo tanto hay varias formas de esperar dicho resultado sin detener los demas procesos del hilo principal.

Por ejemplo, puedes correr un [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321424(v=vs.120)) para realizar tareas en segundo plano y si lo comparas con una tarea asíncrona (AsyncTask), tendrías lo siguiente:

### Ejemplo en C#

---

```
private async void ParseDataAsync(){

    // OnPreExecute

    // Do in Background, se especifica con el operador await, debe ser una tarea asincrona, por ende se puede correr un Task
    await Task.Run(() => {
         // Aqui ejecutas lo que estara en background

    });

    // OnPostExecute
}
```

Y para llamarlo, harías lo siguiente:

**Si estas en un método asíncrono:**

```
await ParseDataAsync();
```

**Si no estas en un método asíncrono:**

Debes retornar [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321424(v=vs.120)) en el método y utilizar el metodo `GetAwaiter()` del [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321424(v=vs.120)), por ejemplo:

```
private async Task ParseDataAsync() {
    . . . 
}
```

y lo llamarías así:

```
ParseDataAsync().GetAwaiter();
```

**Si quieres retornar un valor en un método asíncrono:**

**Debes devolver** `Task<>` **y especificar el parámetro genérico dentro de** `<>`. Por ejemplo, devolver un `int`:

```
private async Task<int> ParseDataAsync() {
        . . . 
       return 0;
}
```

Y para obtener el resultado:

**Si estas en un método asíncrono:**

```
int x = await ParseDataAsync();
```

**Si no estas en un método asíncrono:**

```
int x = ParseDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Puedes ver mas en la documentación oficial acerca de la [programación asíncrona de C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443(v=vs.120)) y los [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321424(v=vs.120)), te serán de mucha ayuda en Xamarin Android.
Esto es un ejemplo de lo que ocurre en un metodo asincrono. Esto es lo que pasa en una tarea asíncrona de C#:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto quiere decir que todo lo que este despues del `await` esta en riesgo. En el caso de Android con las Activitys, debes tener en cuenta que al ejecutar acciones en el UI como ocultar o mostrar un progressbar debes hacer las respectivas validaciones con el ciclo de vida que lo crea. **Por ejemplo** si pones que despues del `await` lanzaras un `Toast`, debes estar seguro que su actividad o contexto que lo crea no este destruido. Un caso de prueba seria, ejecutar una tarea asíncrona al iniciar una actividad y rápidamente cerrarla/destruirla. La tarea asíncrona seguirá en segundo plano y cuando llegue el resultado, al lanzar el `Toast` con un contexto destruido, este te lanzara un error, por tanto debes tener en cuenta que tienes que validar su contexto con un `if(!(Context as Activity).IsDestroyed ?? true))` **antes de realizar las acciones del UI** que involucren a la Actividad padre.

### Tu solucion a tu pregunta:

---

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private Spinner sp;
    private String urlAddress = "localhost:7777/carpeta/buscar.php";
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private JavaList<string> spacecrafts = new JavaList<string>(); 

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        sp = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.sp);
        TextView text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Button downloadBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.downloadBtn);
        downloadBtn.Click += downloadBtn_Click;


    }

    private async void downloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // La llamada a tu Downloader
        new Downloader(this, urlAddress, sp).Execute();

        // Aqui debes obtener el resultado jsonData antes de llamar este metodo      // Puedes convertir tu Downloader a una tarea asincrona de C# si es un AsyncTask
        await ParseDataAsync();
    }

    private async void ParseDataAsync(){
        // OnPreExecute
        ShowProgressDialog();

        int result = 0;
        // Do in Background
        await Task.Run(() => {
             // Aqui ejecutas lo que estara en background
             result = ParseData();
        });

       // OnPostExecute
       DismissDialog();
       BindData(result);
       SetTextViewInfo();
    }

    private void ShowProgressDialog(){

        if(pd == null){
            pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pd.SetTitle("Cargando información");
            pd.SetMessage("Por favor espere");
        }

        pd.Show();
    }

    private int ParseData(string jsonData)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            spacecrafts.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.Length(); i++)
            {
                jo = ja.GetJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.GetString("nomb_ingrediente");
                spacecrafts.Add(name);
            }

            return 1;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private void DismissDialog(){
        pd?.Dismiss(); // Dismiss si pd no es null
    }

    private void BindData(int result){


        if (Integer.ParseInt(result.ToString()) == 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No se puede analizar",ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(c,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, spacecrafts);
            sp.Adapter = adapter;

            // Elimina el evento anterior si existe para evitar duplicarlo
            sp.ItemSelected -= sp_ItemSelected;

            // Agrega el nuevo evento de itemSelected
            sp.ItemSelected += sp_ItemSelected;
        }
    }

    private void sp_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, spacecrafts[e.Position], ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }

    private void SetTextViewInfo(){
        // En este nivel ya tienes la informacion en la lista spacecrafts
        // Creas un string info y vas agregando la informacion de las listas con un foreach
        // Haces en tu textview .Text = info; y listo

    }
}
```